# Why the pdf always exists in statistics textbooks?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, statistics, random-variables

I just jumped into statistics, but what confuses me is that all textbooks seem to assume existence of the probability densify function (pdf) of a R.V.?

For instance, at the beginning, they say there is a dominating measure (Lebesgue measure or counting measure, depending on continuous or discrete cases), and a probability measure. Then they implicitly use the Radon-Nikodym theorem to write the pdf as the R-N derivative.

From real analysis, I know the condition that R-N theorem holds is that the probability measure must be absolutely continuous w.r.t. the dominating measure. But those textbooks do not discuss it.

So my question is why we can use the R-N theorem while no discussion of absolute continuity between the two measures? Is there some point I missed? Thanks!

Comment: Most probability distributions that one encounters in statistics (Normal, Cauchy, Gamma, Binomial,...) have densities w.r.t to Lebesgue measure or the counting measure on $\mathbb N$. These distributions **are** by definition absolutely continuous w.r.t. to Lebesgue/counting measure.

Comment: Do they not explicitly state that a random variable $X$ is continuous before assuming $X$ has a pdf? What's an example?

Comment: @littleO I read Keener's book. It just introduces some measure theory including the R-N theorem in chapter 1, but in chapter 2 it jumps into Exponential Families.

Comment: Every measure is absolutely continuous w.r.t. the counting measure since the latter vanishes only on the empty set. In fact every real probability measure can be decomposed as a sum of a discrete, a continuous and a singular probability measures. It should be said somewhere that they will never work with singular measures, and thus your measure is always a.c.w.r.t. the counting measure and with Lebesgue measure if the discrete part is null.

Comment: I saw "statistics textbooks" and "pdf" and thought this was another question looking for a freely available online text! More specifically, I thought maybe this was a rant about statistics textbooks not having .pdf file versions (with the "not" omitted by accident).

Comment: @tobinz What's the problem with jumping into Exponential families in chapter 2? It sounds like they are not assuming without justification that a random variable is continuous; they are just considering certain random variables that happen to be continuous.